# How to get objective choice field selected index in Blackberry

Tags: blackberry

I have to display items in objective choice Field,based on selected value i have to display another objective choice field how can i do that.How to get selected index value in objective choice field in blackberry.

Thank You

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Say you have an `ObjectChoiceField myCombo;`
which have values from an array.

```
String myValues [] = {"a","b","c"};
myCombo.setChoices(myValues);
```

you can get the selected index by using method:

```
int index = myCombo.getSelectedIndex();
```

and further if you want the selected value. You would use something like:

```
String selectedValue = myValues[myCombo.getSelectedIndex()];
```

See [documentation](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.1api/net/rim/device/api/ui/component/ChoiceField.html#getSelectedIndex%28%29) for further reference.